# Finding $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt n} ( 1 - e^{ i\varphi} + e^{2i\varphi} - \cdots + (-1)^n e^{ni\varphi}\bigr)$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Solve:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \bigl( 1 - e^{i\varphi }+ e^{2i\varphi}- \cdots + (-1)^n e^{ni\varphi}\bigr) $$

I was thinking of replacing $e^{ik\varphi}$ with $i\sin(k\varphi) $ but I got stuck with all sinuses and their sums. Is there any easier way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$$1-e^{ia}+e^{i2a}+...+(-1)^ne^{ina}=\frac{1+(-1)^{n}e^{i(n+1)a}}{1+e^{ia}}$$

Answer (score 0):

When you see an exponent increasing by integer multiples, you should always understand this as $a^{kn}=(a^k)^n=x^n$ so that the exponents are taking on the integers directly; you should then look at the “telescoping series trick”$$
(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^n)=1-x^{n+1}
$$ where we cancel out all of the intermediate terms in the sum by shifting the sequence by one (multiplying by $x$) and then subtracting.